# Chrome won't quit! (Mac Yosemite)

Tags: terminal, macos, google-chrome, permission

I tried normal quit, and it closes and immediately re-opens.
I tried force quit, and it closes and immediately re-opens.
I tried force quit from the Activity Monitor, and it closes and immediately re-opens.
I tried to restart; this was not allowed because Chrome was open.
I turned off using the power button, and turned back on. Chrome opened (despite not being in my login list, and despite me specifying NOT to open the windows that were previously open)
I tried to delete Chrome; not allowed because it's open.
I tried to force quit then immediately delete, but it opens so fast I can't do that.
I used the terminal rm -rf method of deleting, and pages of text appeared, all saying essentially this but with different things between 'contents' and 'permission denied'. `rm: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources: Permission denied`

Does anyone have a clue what's going on? I am out of ideas.

Comment: a black Friday bug :)

Comment: is it opening to a specific web site? Also type about:plugins in the address window and disable all stuff in there and test.

Comment: This sounds like a rap maybe someone can edit it?

Answer (score 11):

That other answer isn't good because you should not shut down your computer, and it is very unlikely that malware has anything to do with not being able to shut down an application. Do this

- Type `sudo killall Google\ Chrome` on the Terminal.
- If this does not work, do this:

  ```
  pgrep -x "Google Chrome"
  ```

  You will see a number, then type `kill -9 numberhere` where `numberhere`  is the number that the `pgrep` command returned.

And to instatly delete the app, no matter if it is open or not, do:

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
```

Then type your password.

The reason you get a permission denied error is because you need root access do to this, just use `sudo` on the terminal for this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

1. Open the Terminal application
2. Type "sudo shutdown -h now" and hit enter.
3. When prompted, enter your password.  You will not see the password as it is typed.  Hit enter once more.

This should immediately force your computer to shut down.  You may have malware on your machine.  I recommend having it scanned.

Cheers,
Byron

Comment: Do you have anything to back up your suggestion of malware being present? Your answer doesn't suggest anything to back up your assertion.

Comment: I second that bug a + from me.

Comment: @douggro: It is not normal behavior for an application to automatically re-open after performing a force-quit.  What do you think may have caused this behavior, if not malware?  Anytime abnormal behavior occurs, there is an increased chance that a machine is infected with malware.

Comment: @ByronFormwalt Don't try to strawman me. ;) I agree that it's not normal behavior. Could be a Chrome bug, could be another process respawning Chrome, could be malware. I just asked you to provide support for your suggestion of malware being the cause, for which you have provided none.

Answer (score 1):

OS (El Captain):

Had the same issue and couldn't restart (menu restart), but chrome wasn't the culprit. My problem stemmed from an issue with the Dock process. After issuing:

```
sudo killall Dock
```

It force restarted my Dock process and cleared up my issue. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing part of what Byron suggested, but rather than a shutdown, force a restart. In Terminal, `sudo restart -h now` followed with your password will force a reboot. When you hear the startup chime, press and hold Command-S to enter single-user mode. Then use `rm -rf` on the Chrome app, and also delete the `~/Library/ApplicationSavedSate/com.Google.Chrome.savedState` directory. Reboot again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me and feels less forced on the machine!

1. Click the Apple on the top left corner
2. "Log Out" of your account
3. RESTART or SHUT DOWN (shut down seemed to work better)

Once I rebooted Chrome was not running and I could dump it in the trash. 
I use Chrome on a daily basis but now I am worried of bringing it back...

Answer (score -1):

I managed to quit chrome by going force quit, and select just chrome.

Comment: OP stated “I tried force quit, and it closes and immediately re-opens.”